# The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a manager for my game however I keep getting this issue in Unity:

> The name 'Assert' does not exist in the current context

Here's my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>
{
    [SerializeField] private Player currentPlayer;

    public Player CurrentPlayer
    {
        get { return currentPlayer; }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(currentPlayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please import the namespace, add

```
using UnityEngine.Assertions;
```

to the top of your file.

Comment: @OwenBaldwin Glad it helped. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Comment: @OwenBaldwin could you mark this as answered? unless you have more to add of course.